# managing third party assets

Tags: git, deployment

I am currently using git for version control but also for deployment. On a web project there is me as a developer and a graphics artist who provides graphical assets such as images and videos.

Our current setup is like that:

1. There is a local repo. I only work in this repo
2. There is a bare repo on a server where local commits are pushed to
3. There is a repo on the webserver that reflects the current projects state
4. When a commit is pushed to the bare repo a post-receive hook is executed which basically pulls the changes into the repo on the webserver

[image]

That works fine, however I don't like the current workflow when grabbing the assets. When the graphics artist has finished some work he always needs to store the assets somewhere. Then I need to grab them and put them into my local repo in order to be able to put them under version control.

So everytime an asset was changed or added I need to manually keep an eye on it and copy it into my repo first.

What I instead would like to do is to let the graphic artist push his changes somewhere and I just could automatically fetch the changes from my local repo.

The problem just now is that I don't know how to tackle the problem best:

- The artist does not need to have the whole repository. For him it should be as simple as pushing his changes
- I don't want the assets to be a *real* part of my repository. I only want to update the assets on demand
- The assets directory should not affect the rest of my repo. So if I commit something I don't want to be forced to pull the latest assets.

** File System representation **

```
/ (<- Local git repo)
-- /css
-- /js
-- /assets (<- the directory that should be provided by the artist)
   -- /img
   -- /video
-- index.html
```

**My ideas so far**

The first thing that came into my mind was to just clone the bare repo for the artist, so that he can commit and push his changes there.

The problem is that he then will have the full repo with all the code, which I don't want. He should just keep his "assets" folder and push his changes somewhere as soon as there are any. Additionally before he can push any changes he would have to update the repo if there were any changes made by me for example.

So that approach is dropped unfortunately.

Is it possible to have *partial* repositories in git, and if yes what would be the best or at least a common approach to accomplish that task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to your problem is [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).  Set up a regular bare repo for your assets and give access to your graphic artist.  He pushes everything to this repo and doesn't need to know about your code.

In your project, you'll add the assets repo as a submodule:

```
git submodule add git@yourgithost.com:your/assets/repo.git assets
```

This will check out the assets repo and install it as a submodule.  At this point you may need to `git add assets` and commit.

The artist can make changes and push without affecting you at all.  Whenever you are ready to bring your repo up-to-date with the latest version of the assets, go to assets/ (which is the assets repo cloned as a submodule) and pull the changes.  Then if you run `git status` in your project root, you'll see something like:

```
modified:   assets (new commits)
```

If you now `git add assets` and commit, the pointer for the assets submodule will be updated.

On the deployment end, you'll need to `git submodule init assets` on the web server to initialize the submodule there, and add `git submodule update` to the hooks on you web server to ensure that it is always using the latest commit you've specified.

Comment: What a great answer! Everythings is logical and very well described.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Wally's answer, you might want to look into git subtrees. Subtrees basically give you a merged copy of another repo's files and there are no .gitsubmodule files to mess with. Submodules are known to be a bit of a pain to manage (https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=git%20submodules%20vs%20subtree).

**Using subtrees**

First merge the assests repo into your main repo. The prefix is the folder where the files will be put, and you need to pass the same prefix to all the 'git subtree' commands. squash squashes down the history of the remote repo to a single commit, this helps to keep the history of your main repo clean.

```
git subtree add --prefix assets [--squash] git@yourgithost.com:your/assets/repo.git master
```

You can then get updates from the assets repo with

```
 git subtree pull --prefix assets [--squash] git@yourgithost.com:your/assets/repo.git master
```

And if you want to change any assets yourself, you can do it in your repo and then push it back to the assets repo with

```
git subtree push --prefix assets git@yourgithost.com:your/assets/repo.git master
```

HINT: Setup aliases for the pull and push commands! You don't need an alias for the subtree add command because you are only going to run it once.